# network problem while running a Ruby on Rails application

Tags: networking, dns, ruby

when I try to run my RoR application I get an error at login that has nothing to do with the code and probably has to do with my network config...this is the error...
`SocketError in SessionsController # create`
`getaddrinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution`
PS: i have tried stackoverflow and usual solutions to solve this and have not been successful.

Comment: What solutions have you tried so far for this (likely) DNS issue?.

Comment: @ChanganAuto nothing regarding DNS...i've tried code base changes to go around this problem but didn't work, i've also tried using diffrent networks and the results were the same